# How set conditional to array value to show my custom string

Tags: php, arrays, loops, drupal, drupal-7

I have checkbox field and I would like to set conditional, if `$array[und][1][value]` equal to special character print something...

**Like this:**

```
switch ($array) {
    case "1": print 'Starts'; break;
    case "3": print 'Roads'; break;
    case "7": print 'Flys'; break;
    case "9": print 'Awesome'; break;
}
```

**Checkbox array :**

```
Array
(
[und] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 1
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [value] => 3
            )

        [42] => Array
            (
                [value] => 7
            )

        [61] => Array
            (
                [value] => 9
            )
    )

)
```

Comment: Are array indexes `1,9,42,61` are static?? If not, you've to put `switch..case` inside `foreach` loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop around `$array['und']` or `$array[LANGUAGE_NONE]` :

```
foreach ($array['und'] as $item) {
    switch ($item['value']) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

You also can get values as :

```
$values = array_column($array['und'],'value')) ; // [1,3,7,9]
```

Comment: @BijanZand You're welcome :) I've updated the awnser to show how to get values directly.